# How to add Page Keyword and Page Description of Products synced to Content tree

Tags: sitecore-commerce

we are adding thousands of products to sitecore commerce via minion from an external application and sitecore data provider shows those products in content tree. But how to add the page Keyword and Page Description for these thousand products.

Sitecore Commerce version is 9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to map the Product descriptions and Page keyword while running the minion and syncing the products from external applications in the commerce engine then send the information to the Sitecore XP side by using Service Proxy Incase you need to find and send specific products. I have described this approach in one my blog posts here at: https://hinagarg5.wixsite.com/website/post/data-exchange-b-w-sitecore-xc-and-xp-by-using-service-proxy-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Sitecore Powershell Extension ?
You can bulk update many Sitecore objects just with a script.
I have just written an article about it:
https://jesuissitecore.com/2020/08/03/import-and-export-data-outside-sitecore/

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I have gone through your post and in our case the product field values of sitecore commerce changes frequently via minion. so i am looking for a workaround in sitecore commerce connect data provider which can handle this changes